# How to disable ctrl keys , alt keys , window keys in Vb 6?

Tags: vb6

Im trying to make a cafe management for our project. I want to disable keys (start button, <kbd>alt+f4</kbd>, <kbd>alt+tab</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl+alt+delete</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl+escape</kbd> , <kbd>window</kbd> key). anybody knows how to do this ? please help! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reccommend doing this through group policy configuration or local/machine policys. implementing this via an application will get you flagged by virus/malware scanners.

to remove CTRL+ALT+DEL, check out: 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/e885bcfc-42a8-4482-9500-4865f0de3a06/windows-server-2008-r2-gpo-to-disable-ctrlaltdel-totally-or-disable-shutdown-and-restart?forum=winserverTS

the other have simular policies.

Answer (score 0):

Set your program to be the Windows shell. That takes out most keys (not CAD though, but people need to reboot when your program crashes).

At `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` set `shell` to path and name of your program.

Windows will now boot to your program, will shutdown if your program shuts down. If yours is the only program they can't Alt + Tab anywhere as there is no other program to Alt + Tab to.

You may set these Group Policies - Run dialog, CMD prompt, and Task Manager.

Answer (score 0):

From my old library but can't test anymore.

```
Declare Function SystemParametersInfo Lib "user32" Alias "SystemParametersInfoA" _
     (ByVal uAction As Long, ByVal uParam As Long, ByRef lpvParam As Any, _
    ByVal fuWinIni As Long) As Long
Const SPI_SCREENSAVERRUNNING = 97

' Enable/Disable key combinations :
' CTRL+ALT+SUPPR, CTRL+ESC et ALT+TAB
Sub CTRL_ALT_SUPPR(blOFF As Boolean)
' blOFF = True, to disable combinations
' blOFF = False, to enable combinations
Dim lgRep As Long
lgRep = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SCREENSAVERRUNNING, blOFF, False, 0)
End Sub
```